# iOS7 Storyboard image picker not working :(

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, storyboard, segue

Im trying to set up an `imagePicker` in a new iOS7 Xcode project using storyboards but can't seem to find any examples online until I found the following code.

I've set it up so that when a button is pressed it uses a modal push thing to navigate to the view which has the class of `"UIImagePickerController"` which apparently calls in the image picker code.

However when the app is run it won't load anything up after clicking on allow the application to access your photos any chance of some help please?

**Error screen shot grab:** https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Bdy7v9JCAAABpvS.jpg:large

**interface setup:**

```
@interface ridecount_AddRide_ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
```

**code:**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    controller.delegate = self;
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [[self.view viewWithTag:100023] removeFromSuperview];
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320/2-200/2, 10, 100, 100)];
    imageView.tag = 100023;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.image = image;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initialize the controller *`UIImagePickerController *controller = [[segue destinationViewController] init];`*

Comment: Why isn't the storyboard init'ing the view controller ? Isn't that strange behavior? But thanks! It works :)

Comment: thx, your [[segue destinationViewController] init] approach saves me from using an ugly void segue workaround

Comment: @AvnerBarr the true is that the storyboard initialize `destinationViewController` with `initWithCoder:` method. When the `UIImagePickerController` is initialized programatically (not from storyboard) with the `init` method, it probably makes some additional stuff comparing to `initWithCoder:` method. That is why it is not fully working using storyboard. I don't recommend performing `init...` method one more time in `prepareForSegue` body. The object shouldn't be initialized more than once. Please check my answer with the alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

for SWIFT - bit different approach

```
//Init property
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
```

then assign

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    imagePicker = segue.destinationViewController as UIImagePickerController
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The `UIImagePickerController` object which was initialized from the storyboard worked correctly only when the `availableMediaTypesForSourceType` was set to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

If you want to preserve `prepareForSegue:` functionality you can remove the `UIImagePickerController` from the storyboard and create it programatically using the following code:

```
- (void)showCameraRollController
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:@"CameraRollController" source:self destination:imagePickerController performHandler:^{
        [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }];
    [self prepareForSegue:segue sender:self];
    [segue perform];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CameraRollController"]) {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [segue destinationViewController];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, another alternative is to subclass UIImagePickerController and add to the subclass:

`- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        return [super init];
    }`

It seemed to work.